# How do I move an existing window to a new tab?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to take an existing window (split) and put it into a new tab?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

As well as the previously suggested `:tabedit` approach, a quicker way of doing it is (in normal mode) to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>.  Ctrl-W is the general prefix for a wide variety of window manipulation commands.

See:

```
:help Ctrl-W_T
:help Ctrl-W
```

Comment: Note that `help Ctrl-W_T` takes you to the help entry of `Ctrl-W_t` (lower case), however, further down the page is the `Ctrl-W_T` entry (with capital T), saying "Move the current window to a new tab page...."

Comment: @DrAl and how we move a new tab window to split window?

Comment: @RamizUddin There's no simple way of doing this (as it isn't obvious which window you want to split into).  However, you can find out the buffer number for your current tab page with `:echo bufnr("")` and using this number you can split a window with `:sp #3` or `:sb 3` (assuming the number was 3).  You may be able to come up with some mappings or functions to simplify this.

Comment: How do you _move_ the buffer to a new tab, keeping it's undo/redo state. In other words, I don't want to open the same file in a new tab, I want to literally _move_ the buffer to a new tab, so the edit history can be used in the new tab. If there is no default way to do this, I bet a plugin can be made that adds a new shortcut for doing this that writes the undo history to the swap file for the new buffer.

Comment: @trusktr I'd imagine that opening the buffer in a new tab with `:sb` would work, but with recent versions of Vim (>= 7.3) you can also use persistent undo by setting `set undodir=/path/to/dir` where /path/to/dir is a directory you've created for the purpose and then  `set undofile`.  This will allow you quit vim and then restart and still retain the undo/redo state.

Comment: I like `:tabedit` better because when you `wq` the edit it still keeps the code open in the original window

Comment: You got my vote for having __shift__ `T` in your answer, I totally missed the shift key and was wondering why it wasn't working (one reason that I didn't get it myself is that I was struggling with mapping Ctrl keys, and there it is no difference between `t` and `T`).

Comment: Man this is hard to find... Ok in the end it fits in the "moving windows around" section of the manual, but couldn't they put at least a mention in the tabpage.txt section as well??

Answer (score 108):

Try

```
:tabedit %<CR>
```

Comment: Just curious why you included the <CR> with that.

Comment: For the same reason I did include ":". This is the complete vim keys combination in normal mode and you can use this in 'nnoremap' and in 'nmap'

Comment: This one didn't work for me.  It opens the new tab for a second, but then closes it for some reason.  Must be some issue with a setting or plugin I have.  DrAl's solution below worked though.

Comment: This works as well except it clones/duplicates the window to a new tab as opposed to closing it first and then opening it in a new tab. Not a big deal. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: This doesn't move the buffer to a new tab, it just opens the same file in a new tab, but you will not have undo/redo history, etc.

Comment: `C-w T` is faster way to do the same thing

Comment: If you're using neovim then use `vim.cmd("tabedit %:p")` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This moves the newest buffer in a new tab and restores the previous buffer in the current tab.
I use this after dragging a new file into my Gvim

```
:sbp |wincmd p| wincmd T
```

You can map it like that to Ctrl-Backspace

```
:nnoremap <C-BS> :sbp<bar>wincmd p<bar>wincmd T<CR>
```

it performs especially well with

```
:set switchbuf=usetab
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_current_window_between_tabs) which gives you two functions which can be bound to a pair of hotkeys or commands, and which works quite intuitively. I am pretty sure it offers behavior even more friendly than e.g. `Ctrl-W_T`.

For example, when multiple windows are open in multiple tabs, using this function allows you to specifically move the current window to the next or previous tab, and if you move something to before the first tab or to after the last tab, then it turns into a whole new tab.

This means if you have 2 tabs, each having a single window, then moving the first tab's window to the right will combine it with the second tab to result in one single tab with two windows. I don't know how convoluted this operation is to achieve using traditional commands.

What this means is that a single pair of move commands allows for both shifting windows around the tabs, splitting windows out into tabs (by pushing a window out to the end) and joining separate tabs into windows inside of a single tab, pretty much everything you could possibly want, short of positional arrangement (which is a separate topic and which the built in `Ctrl-W`+`Shift-HJKL` commands work fine for).

Comment: Very elegant. Moved windows maintain history. Tabs are created if there’s none at the requested end. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'll note that 9 years later I transitioned to a lua config and tried to port this vimscript into neovim lua code, but I failed. Never got it even close to working properly. So i gave up and shoved these into the VimL execution string that I already have (and is still pretty big) and I got this feature back again. It sucked not having it working right for a while.

Comment: My Neovim just inherited the large init.vim I had before with vanilla Vim, including this. I am guessing it could be faster if I go all lua with lazy loading but it works in meantime…

Comment: yeah and if you ever make a robust lua port of this functionality, i'd love to know about it, the lua api isnt great in this area of window manipulation.